# Data set of automobile performance

Tags: cars

Is there an open data set of car performance? By year, manufacturer and model? I'm looking for all kinds of measurements such as 0-60 time, engine displacement, mpg, 1/4 mile time, 60-0, etc.

In the absence of an open set, I may contact publications like *Motor Trend* or *Road & Track* to see if they have a table they can share.

Answer (score 1):

So you need the information for the US car market or for worldwide car market? Under performance you mean a sheet of technical specs?
How about Edmunds.com if their information is still available?  They used to offer free access to their cars database for developers - i have used them few years ago.
My recent collisions with the automotive magazines testify that the majority of them will not open their databases without any payment. Sad story. If you have the time check out the following [car catalog](https://www.auto-data.net/en/) (they have a nice set of specifications - the ones you need but you might need to use a converter to calculate the km/h into mph and etc. If you change your ming and decide to go payed - check this [car data provider](https://www.car-database-api.com/vehicle-api-parameters).

P.s. I think Edmnuds is still working no idea to what extent though.